# Read through a text file and increment a variable every time an equals sign is encountered

Tags: c, variables, text-files, increment

I'm trying to write a program which will read through a makefile, and increment a counter every time an equals '=' sign is encountered in the file. Here is my attempt at such a program (the incrementation is not the sole purpose of this program, it just happens to be the point at which I am currently stuck):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct VarMap {
    int data;
    int key;
};

// Use a hash table to store the variables - variablename : definition
void processFile(FILE* spData) {
    
    int varCount = 0;
    char buffer[1000];
    while (fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , spData) != NULL) {
        if (buffer[0] == '#') continue;
        for (int i = 0; i != '\0' ; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '=') {
                varCount++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("varCount has counted %d equals signs.\n\n" , varCount);
    
    // This will hold the variables
    struct VarMap variables[varCount];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    char filepath[1000];
    printf("Enter the filepath of the Bakefile or bakefile: ");
    scanf("%s" , filepath);
    FILE* spData = fopen(filepath , "r");
    if (spData == NULL) {
        printf ("Cannot open file.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    processFile(spData);
    
    fclose(spData);
    return 0;
}
```

The function we are interested in is the *processFile* function. My flow of reasoning was to read the file, line by line, into the array *buffer*, and then parse through the array until the first equals sign is found, at which I will increment *varCount* and `continue` to the next line. I can then use this variable to initialise a keymap to store the pairs of values corresponding to the variable names and their contents.

My issue is that the program, as written, is consistently returning *0 equals signs*, whenever I run it and input the file with the following contents (obviously there exists equals signs but they are not being picked up):

```
calcmarks : calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -o calcmarks \
        calcmarks.o globals.o readmarks.o correlation.o -lm


calcmarks.o : calcmarks.c calcmarks.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c calcmarks.c

globals.o : globals.c calcmarks.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c globals.c

readmarks.o : readmarks.c calcmarks.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c readmarks.c

correlation.o : correlation.c calcmarks.h
    cc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -c correlation.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o calcmarks
```

As you may have guessed, I am trying to write an implementation in C for a program which can process a Makefile! Not an easy job, sadly.

So my question is;

**What am I doing wrong / missing which is preventing varCount from being incremented?**

Comment: This `i != '\0' ` ===> `buffer[i] != '\0' `. or `buffer[i] != '\n'` is better as `fgets()` stores the `\n` char at the end of buffer.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `continue`. First of all it doesn't continue to the "next line", it continues the *loop* (possibly skipping statements).

Comment: @achal Thanks a ton; I am beyond embarrassed with myself that I missed that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test condition for for loop should be:

```
buffer[i] != '\0'
```

Thanks to @achal for pointing it out.